# how to disable keyboard popup on mobile devices on mobile webpage input?

Tags: android, jquery, mobile-website

I have a Textbox on my webpage, how do I disable the keyboard popup on Android/mobile devices?  Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" style="position:relative; top:5px; left:300px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make text element `disabled` or `readonly`. But remember the difference between `disabled` and `readonly`: browser don't send to server `disabled` elements.